# Excel macro executes in debug mode but throws an error when different sheet is selected

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I am writing a macro to transfer data from an input form to a storage table.
I have the rough code worked out, and it runs. Only if i have the destination sheet selected. If i try to run it from the sheet containing the form it throws the following error:
`Run-time error '1004': Select method of Range class failed`
But yet if i run the macro from the destination sheet it executes flawlessly.
Here is the code:

```
Sub ExpFormCharge()
    Dim pasteCell As Range
    Range("expenseTbl").ListObject.ListRows.Add AlwaysInsert:=False
    Range("ETBMARKER").Offset(-1, 0).Select
    Range("ExpFormBackend").Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

The backend table is filled by another macro and this table is then copied and pasted into a new row in the expense table(the storage table). The line that is highlighted by the debug option is this one:
`Range("ETBMARKER").Offset(-1, 0).Select`
That refers to a marker, the total row of the storage table offset one so as to select the bottom row of the table.
This error occurs whenever a sheet other than the destination sheet is selected whether the code is executed from the vba window or from the macro selection pane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certain operations can only be performed on the Active sheet.

Add

```
Range("ETBMARKER").Parent.Activate
```

before the line throwing the error.

Just an aside, but you Dim a variable that you never use, and the line causing the error doesn't do anything -- you copy a different range on the very next line.  You could remove those two lines, unless there is additional functionality you haven't included in this code sample.